# How to avoid specifying the same type twice in trait implementation?

Tags: rust

I remember there was a way to define a trait so that you will not need to write this:

```
trait A<T> {
    fn f();
}

impl A<T> for T {
    fn f() {}
}
```

As far as I can remember, it was possible to shorten the `impl A<T> for T` line like this:

```
impl A for T {
```

I don't recall the exact recipe of doing this. I believe there is a term related to such a shortening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ingredient you're looking for is **Default Type Parameters**, where you could make `T` default to `Self`:

```
trait A<T = Self> {
    fn f();
}

struct Tee;
impl A for Tee {   // the "A" is A<Self>, i.e. A<Tee>.
    fn f() {} 
}
```

In the standard library, the [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) trait is an example using this.